# Save filter view Excel 365

Tags: excel, office365

I have a huge Excel spreadsheet (36 columns) and applied filters on the header row. I made some configuration and now I have the filtered sheet.

Is it possible to save this filter configuration?

There was the option back in MS2007 (Custom views) but I cant find it in Excel 365.

Answer (score 1):

In the "View" ribbon select "Custom Views" in the group "Workbook Views". If it does not appear go to options->customize ribbon-> select all commands-> find "Custom Views"-> add to a custom ribbon.

After filtering your table, click on "Custom Views" -> Add

This will save the table filtering among other things.

Keep in mind that Custom Views are worksheet-specific, meaning that a custom view only applies to the worksheet that was active when you created the custom view.

Comment: I added the custom views command to an extra custom group and was able to 'save' the filter settings (with a specific name). How can I now revert to it? When I select the filtername nothing happens

Comment: I created a second view (to switch between the two) but it does nothing. It always changes back to the last created one. At least with the name, the filter settings in the sheet are still not affected

Comment: Is your table formatted as an excel table? That could be the issue as they are not supported in custom views. Try opening a new workbook, create a small list and apply a filter-> save custom view-> remove the filter from the list -> click custom view and select the saved view. It works from here

Comment: Creating a new workbook and inserting a dummy table enables the custom view feature. My original data was inserted from a .csv file, but then I saved it as .xlsx. Shouldnt it be an excel table now?

Comment: Creating new workbook and copy the data into the presumable excel table also does not work.

Comment: There is a specific feature (Format as table in the home ribbon), but i guess you are not using that, no worries.  I can't really tell what you are doing wrong. See this link for further explanation: [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-apply-or-delete-a-custom-view-ce722bf9-0b4a-49a5-94ba-438fde18fc2b)

Comment: In some cases it works (newly generated data), but copied data wont let me choose a custom view. I even loaded it via Notepad++ configured the semicolon to Tabs and copied it into Excel with no luck. My 'solution' now is loading the data with libre calc filtering and saving it as xlsx in the configuration I need (for further processing for my colleagues). The continuous processing I will do in Calc since the feature is working without any problems

Answer (score 0):

You can create a macro that will apply the filters to the table.

1. Developer Tab
2. Record Macro
3. Apply filters to table (you can even just edit the filter for each column and select "OK" to apply the filter you already have in place)
4. Stop recording Macro

From then on you can just run the macro you recorded and it will filter your table.